# Traducir error laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Estoy haciendo una importación utilizando el paquete de maatwebsite excel, estoy mostrando los errores de validación, pero necesito traducir o cambiar el texto que especifica en que fila esta el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este esta es mi validacion:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        
        'ncf'                       => 'required|min:11',
        'tipo_de_ingreso'           => 'required',
        'fecha_de_comprobante'      => 'required',
        'monto_facturado'           => 'required',
        'itbis_facturado'           => 'required|numeric',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dentro de la carpeta resource/lang/ crea un archivo que tengo el nombre de es.json, dentro vas a colocar cadenas en forma de json

{
"There was an error on row :row. :message": "Hubo un error en la fila :row. :message"
}

como en este ejemplo que es el caso puntual que necesitas.

https://github.com/Laraveles/spanish/tree/master/resources/lang

En este link puedes encontrar las traducciones en laravel incluso el archivo es.json puedes descargarlo y pegarlo en tu proyecto

y en la linea final de todas las que ya tienen generadas, pegas lo mismo de arriba

"There was an error on row :row. :message": "Hubo un error en la fila :row. :message"

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages, de igual forma si lo que quieres es traducir los mensajes por defecto Laravel incluye los archivos de traducción en la ruta "resources/lang/xx/validation.php" para mas informacion revise la documentacion:  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-messages-for-specific-attributes

Tambien puedes instalar el siguiente paquete de traducciones con el comando `composer require laraveles/spanish`, para mas informacion te copio el link de GitHub https://github.com/Laraveles/spanish